# BouncyCastle.Crypto dll issue with iTextSharp ver 5.5.13.2

Tags: c#, itext

We are trying to upgrade the itextsharp to version 5.5.13.2 but ended up with getting the exception as below:

> Could not load file or assembly 'bouncycastle.crypto, version=1.8.6.0, culture=neutral, PublickeyToken=0e99375e54769942' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I cannot really add a new dll (BouncyCastle.Crypto) to resolve this issue. Please suggest an alternative for this.

Comment: There is no alternative, it's a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of iTextsharp and switch to http://www.pdfsharp.net/. Open source, does everything itextsharp does. Plus you don't have to figure out the complicated licensing that itextsharp has recently imposed.

Comment: That is not a solution if you have large project with a lot of using of iTextSharp dll...